# How can I generate column in R which has Pairwise of one column

Tags: r

V1  ------> FA MA GA RA TA

I want to have output like below

column1 -> FA FA FA FA  MA MA MA GA GA

column2 -> MA GA  RA TA GA RA TA RA TA

Comment: Possible to provide sample data that better represent the true data? What kind of output you are looking for? Combination starts with FA? Or all? And need to paste elements together?...

Comment: Well my data is just bunch of names i am trying to find similarity with . SO this FA MA are just names

Comment: @sunitha So you just want only one column ie. `column2`?  What is `V1`?

Comment: just random heading i gave . yes i just want column 2. I hope i am more clear with what output i want.

Comment: @sunitha You showed `column1` with values `FA MA GA`, and you want column2 ` with `MA GA RA TA`.  It is not clear or either your input column1 have typos.

Comment: yes your correct . i have big data set so it should pair up with whole data . i think you got my point

Comment: @sunitha suppose your input dataset is `dat <- data.frame(V1= rep(c("FA", "MA", "GA", "RA", "TA"), c(4,3,2, 3, 4)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` Could you show the expected `column2` based on the `V1`?

Comment: hey you got the column two write in your previous comment . when i am defining data frame i cannot individually type in all the row names told before it is big data.

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion i am novice in programming so .

Comment: @sunitha You haven't given the expected output for the small dataset I created.

Comment: The second column starts with the second row in column one in your data set it will be MA GA RA and so on......

Comment: Maybe you are just looking for the output of `t(combn(V1, 2))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `length` generated by the `unique` combination of rows/elements of column `V1` would be greater than the `nrow` of `dat`.  So, I am not sure how you want to generate a new column `V2` on the same dataset.  Perhaps you can create another dataframe with a single column

```
 dat2 <- data.frame(V2=combn(unique(dat$V1),2, FUN=paste, collapse="."), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 dat2$V2
 #[1] "FA.MA" "FA.GA" "FA.RA" "FA.TA" "MA.GA" "MA.RA" "MA.TA" "GA.RA" "GA.TA"
 #[10] "RA.TA"
```

If you need to paste the first value with all the others

```
 paste(dat$V1[1], dat$V1[-1], sep=".")
 #[1] "FA.MA" "FA.GA" "FA.RA" "FA.TA"
```

#### Update

If you need don't need to `paste`, then (as mentioned by @aosmith) you can just do:

```
  dat2 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(unique(dat$V1),2)))
  dat2
  #   V1 V2
  #1  FA MA
  #2  FA GA
  #3  FA RA
  #4  FA TA
  #5  MA GA
  #6  MA RA
  #7  MA TA
  #8  GA RA
  #9  GA TA
  #10 RA TA
```

#### data

```
 dat <- data.frame(V1=c("FA", "MA", "GA", "RA", "TA"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: okay the output in dat2$V2 is perfect how can i split them up into two columns???

Comment: @sunitha I updated the post.  But, I still am confused about the output for `dat` I created on the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with `combn` function, which generates all combinations. For example, we want combinations of a, b, c by two elements:

```
 v <- c("a", "b", "c")
 combn(v, 2)
```

Would result as combinations matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

If you want this matrix as vector of pairs, you can apply `paste` over the columns and collapse it by "." - a dot:

```
apply(combn(v, 2), 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "."))
```

This would give you vector of characters combinations - `"a.b" "a.c" "b.c"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> for(i in 1:(length(V1)-1))
         V2[i] = paste(V1[1], V1[i+1],sep='.')
> V2
[1] "FA.MA" "FA.GA" "FA.RA" "FA.TA"
```